# Long-running Openshift Cron

Tags: python, cron, flask, openshift, nohup

I have a long-running daily cron on OpenShift. It takes a couple hours to run. I've added nohup and I'm running it in the background. It still seems to timeout at the default 5 minutes (It works appropriately for this time). I'm receiving no errors and it works perfectly fine locally.

> nohup python ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}wsgi/manage.py do_something >> \
>   ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}do_something_data.log 2> \
>   ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}do_something_error.log &

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: I have been told 5 minutes is the limit for the free accounts.  That includes all background processes.  I asked a similar question here on SO.

Comment: Well that does it. Thanks. Feel free to answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm lazy. Cut and paste :)

I have been told 5 minutes is the limit for the free accounts. That includes all background processes. I asked a similar question here on SO.